# What is the reason I am getting a different date when using toLocaleDateString?

Tags: javascript, date

When finding a festivity that exists within an array of objects and when trying to print a user friendly message using `toLocaleDateString` I get the festivity date with one day less than when `toLocaleDateString` is executed

Please look at the following example

```js
const date = "12/25/2020";
const [month, day, year] = date.split("/");
const newDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
const holidays = [
  { celebration: "New year", date: "2020-12-31" },
  { celebration: "Christmas", date: "2020-12-25" },
  { celebration: "...", date: "2020-12-24" },
];
const holiday = holidays.find((holiday) => holiday.date === newDate);

if (holiday) {
  const { celebration, date } = holiday;
  const options = {
    month: "long",
    day: "2-digit",
  };
  const localDate = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
  const message = `Date ${date} coincides with the holiday ${celebration} in date ${localDate}. Do you want to continue?`;

  console.log(message);
}
```

I get `Date 2020-12-25 coincides with the holiday Christmas in date December 24. Do you want to continue?`

I expect `Date 2020-12-25 coincides with the holiday Christmas in date December 25. Do you want to continue?`

It's a subtle detail but i get `24` instead of `25`

Comment: I think the issue is due to timezone. I am getting the right output. My timezone is IST.

Comment: When I rn this code in my browser it prints correctly `Date 2020-12-25 coincides with the holiday Christmas in date December 25. Do you want to continue?`

Comment: Try using `newDate` instead of `date`

Comment: I searched for `what is my timezone` in google and I got Central Standard Time

Comment: Phil I tried `newDate` instead of `date` `new Date(newDate).toLocaleDateString("en-US", options)` but I am getting the same result

Answer (score 3):

It most likely is due to the timezones. I would assume that you are based in the Americas.

When you create a date using `Date(string)` it creates the date using UTC, but when you're displaying it it shows the date in your own timezone, so any date west of UTC/GMT would show 2020-12-25T00:00Z as happening in 2020-12-24.

Also, parsing using `Date` can differ from implementation to implementation, so it's generally recommended using a library such as Moment.js to do the parsing (and can also handle timezones correctly).

Comment: Thanks for answering Jimmy. I will give it a try to momentjs

Comment: "*When you create a date using Date(string) it creates the date using UTC*" mostly, no. "2020-12-31" is parsed as UTC, but "12/25/2020" (and many other formats) is not.

Comment: @RobG, no, that is correct, but support for those are not a guarantee either. And, tbh, in my opinion should not be used. 12/25/2020 is easy, but say 10/11/2020 it means differently depending if you're in UK (d/m/y) or US (m/d/y), the parser can't know which one to use. The only supported formats in Date is ISO-8601 and by convention RFC 2822. All others are up to each engine and browser to interpret as they like, and generally not recommended to use because of the ambiguity.